# Is T distribution symmetric ?

Tags: distributions, t-distribution

Is student t distribution (Multivariate) symmetric ? On Wikipedia it also says its symmetric https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution.
But my adviser is  saying its not symmetric all the time. Is that true ?

Comment: You may be thinking of the central t-distribution.The non-central t-distribution has different properties: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution

Comment: There is also a skew-$t$ distribution: http://azzalini.stat.unipd.it/SN/